# Invalid object name from SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> Invalid object name 'Members'

on this line:

```
int MemberExist = (int)check_Member.ExecuteScalar();
```

With my current DB which looks like this: http://imgur.com/6fyKGn3 Why wouldn't this be executing?

Code:

```
// Get the connection 
SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""E:\DS\Prac5\Part1\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataReader Reader = null;

DBConnection.Open();
SqlCommand check_Member = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE MembershipID = FirstName AND LastName = @Txtnput", DBConnection);
check_Member.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Txtnput", txtMembershipid.Text);

int MemberExist = (int)check_Member.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: change Mydatabase.mdf to Database.mdf and remove " in between check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

seems some error in your connection string.

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename='E:\DS\Prac5\Part1\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf'
```

You can also use

```
"SELECT TOP 1 MembershipID  FROM Members WHERE MembershipID = FirstName AND LastName = @Txtnput"
```

Make Sure your Table name is  **Members**.  You can check that in the Model or Database.

```
bool IsMemberExist;
object MembershipId = check_Member.ExecuteScalar();

if(MembershipId  != null )
 {
   IsMemberExist = true;
  //Do other things here.  //Convert.ToInt32(MembershipId) 
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately my table is most definitely the correct name as you can see by my imgur link I posted.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you my connection string was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that whether you database `MyDatabase.mdf` contain the table named `Members`.
Please test with following.

```
SqlCommand check_table= "select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '" + tableName + "')) then 1 else 0 end");
int IsTableExists = (int)check_table.ExecuteScalar();
if(IsTableExists ==1)
{
        SqlCommand check_Member = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE MembershipID = FirstName AND LastName = @Txtnput", DBConnection);
        check_Member.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Txtnput", txtMembershipid.Text);
        int MemberExist = (int)check_Member.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

UPDATE:
can you please update the query with schema name along with table name.

eg: `SqlCommand check_Member = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Members WHERE MembershipID = FirstName AND LastName = @Txtnput", DBConnection);`

**Or** more specifically `MyDatabase.dbo.Members`

Comment: it does as far as i'm aware :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to change the queries to become

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM Members WHERE MembershipID = FirstName AND LastName = @Txtnput"
```

Because `ExecutesScalar` expects a single value return from a query.

Comment: Hmm I just tried that but it's still giving me same exception. "Invalid object name 'Members'."

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string and check

```
    SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename=E:\DS\Prac5\Part1\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
```

remove the " in between no need because start with @  also change MyDatabase.mdf to Database.mdf because in picture it is Database.mdf

Comment: @user4814432 check this